# On compiling macOS app throws the following error: kCFURLVolumeIsAutomountedKey missing for file:

Tags: xcode, build, swift3, macos-sierra

macOS 10.12
Xcode: Version 8.0 (8A218a)

When building the application it throws the following error.

kCFURLVolumeIsAutomountedKey missing for file:///private/var/setup/: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “setup” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///private/var/setup/, NSFilePath=/private/var/setup, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000000400c0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Has anybody met with this? Is it a Sierra type of problem?

Comment: I have similar error, but in Rails development environment ) When running webkit tests in rspec. I've also just upgraded to Sierra:  webkit_server[16396:3172510] kCFURLVolumeIsAutomountedKey missing for file:///private/var/setup/: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “setup” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///private/var/setup/, NSFilePath=/private/var/setup, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9605604990 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Answer (score 0):

`xcode-select --install` will fix it by installing the Xcode Command Line Tools.

You may also need to restart your mac to unmount the odd file system that is mounted at `/private/var/setup`.